# beatifulsoup for Visual Studio Python

Tags: visual-studio, beautifulsoup

I am using `Visual Studio` for Python. I a would like to install Beatifulsoup for web scraping. `Python 3.4` installed as interpreter.

I installed BS but does not work. Could you please help me in order to use `Beatifulsoup` in `Visual Studio`.

I executed below code and I get "no module named bs4" error. Thanks

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
print(bsObj.h1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is already in the Continuum Anaconda platform.

You can download the entire package from here: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Select the Operative System and computer architecture where the package is going to be installed.

A .exe file is going to be downloaded.

Double-click the .exe file to install Anaconda and follow the instructions on the screen.

With that, BeautifulSoup4 will be installed, and this package also includes a lot of other very useful libraries. This package is amazing, actually, I really recommend it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code at Visual studio terminal:
pip install beautifulsoup4